# Read input from command line into the shell script exec using golang

Tags: shell, go, pipe

I am using go to run a shell script using exec.command like below and I want to take an input argument using command line say `i`, and my output should be based on `i`, how would I do that?

```
i := os.Args[1:2]
out, err := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "tail -n 1 /var/log/apache2/access.log | awk '{print $i/1024}' >> mem_usage.csv").Output()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
    return
 }
```

How could I use that i in the shell script?

Without `i` it works fine i.e if I put `$1` or `$2` it works fine but I want user to give me the position of `i` and then calculate accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to format the `exec`-command string accordingly.

So ie:

`fmt.Sprintf("awk '{print $%d/1024}'", i)`

This gives: `awk '{print $1/1024}'` for `i = 1` and `awk '{print $2/1024}'` for `i = 2`

`fmt.Sprintf` takes a format string and the arguments to pass into this string and returns the formatted string. (https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf)

And this needs to be inserted into your `exec`-command:

```
i := 2
awkPart := fmt.Sprintf("awk '{print $%d/1024}'", i)
out, err := exec.Command("bash", "-c", "tail -n 1 /var/log/apache2/access.log | "+awkPart+" | tee -a mem_usage.csv").Output()
```

You should maybe try to disassemble your command a bit more for maintainabilty, but that's not part of the question.

Comment: i dont understand how it would work, we have to pipe the first part output to the awk, it is showing error when i do the things you said syntax error: unexpected awk, expecting comma or ) can you please eloberate a little bit more?
 invalid character literal (more than one character) @mstruebing

Comment: Are you sure `i` is set?

Comment: thanks sir, but it overwrites the file, as you have removed the '>>' in the script?

Comment: then use `tee -a` for append.